# Why does JQuery show/hide work for button but not for a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to toggle the showing or hiding of a button and a div based on a condition. Currently, the JQuery hide is working for the button() but the show() is not for the div. In other words, in the javascript below, if the condition is met, the button is hidden but the div does not show.

html:

```
<button type="button" id="my-button" onclick="...do something">Go</button>
<div id="my-text">Please send an email to help@mycompany.com</div>
```

css:

```
#my-text{
    display: none;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var someConditionIsMet = //...compute something
            if (someConditionIsMet) {
                $('#my-button').hide();
                $('#my-text').show();
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

However if I change it to

```
            if (someConditionIsMet) {
                $('#my-button').hide();
                $('#my-text').attr("style", "display:block")
            }
```

then it works properly. I thought show was basically changing the display style to block so I'm not sure why I have to spell it out like this. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle for this

Comment: its working see http://jsfiddle.net/tWQwQ/1/

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/tWQwQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify your code a bit to

```
$('#my-button, #my-text').toggle();
```

that will togle the visibility of the elements, however that probably does not solve your problem it might very well be related to how you hid the div in the first place. Try changing that to .hide() instead of setting the css manually. There's a few ways to hide an element .show reverts just one of them (the same used for hide())

Comment: Could you tell me what are the other ways to hide an element? According to http://api.jquery.com/hide/,  .hide() "is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none')". Thanks.

Comment: Placing it outside the screen, below other elements, setting visibility, zero size

Answer (score 0):

`show` works for me in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWQwQ/3/). Are you sure your conditions are being met? Try throwing an `alert('conditions met');` inside the `if` to see if its being triggered.

Comment: yup already checked that. I have tried putting all sorts of alerts and printing to console inside if and its definately going in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning `aria-hidden` attributes, then using jQuery to hide anything that you've designated as hidden to screen readers.

Code:

```
<button type="button" id="my-button" onclick="...do something" aria-hidden="true">Go</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('[aria-hidden="true"]').hide(); //hide anything that's marked as hidden to screen-readers
```

Then use .hide() and .show(), with a toggle for the `aria-hidden` attribute.

See a [working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/4kNPF/](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/4kNPF/)

Comment: See [http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) for more on aria-hidden.